# Google Cloud logging driver for docker doesn't collect logs

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm  running a Docker container with a Python application that writes logs to the `stdout` with the Python standard `logging` lib. The container is not hosted in any Google Cloud product but on my own machine.

I configured docker to use the `gcplogs` driver as described on [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver) and the official [driver docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/).

The docker container runs with no problems. However, no logs are being collected because I don't see anything on the Stackdriver logging viewer, other than some weird "ping" log entries that are produced on each execution of the docker container.

[image]

The python logger is configured via `dictConfig`:

```
'console': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    'formatter': 'simple',
    'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
},
```

The docker container is ran with this command:

```
docker run --env-file `pwd`/.env \
       --label app=oncrm \
       --log-driver=gcplogs \
       --log-opt gcp-meta-name= host_name\
       --log-opt gcp-project=cloud_project_id \
       --log-opt labels=app \
       --name oncrm \
       --net host \
       --rm \
       -v `pwd`/data:/code/data \
       -v `pwd`/logs:/code/logs \
docker_image sh update_subs.sh
```

The driver documentation doesn't really specify where are log being collected from but it does mention that the driver should also work outside the Google Cloud Platform/Products.

Environment:

- Python 3.6.4 (official DockerHub image for Alpine3.7)
- Docker-ce 18.03.0
- Ubuntu 17.10
- Stackdriver Premium tier

Comment: Do you have gcloud installed on your machine ? Are you logged ?

Comment: @Alexandre I had it, and it is logged-in. However, that won't make a difference because login credentials are obtained via `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` which is the only authentication method supported by the driver. Before setting that env var I had authentication error messages, but that's not the case anymore.

Comment: Is Stackdriver logging API is Enabled ?
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/logging.googleapis.com/overview

Is your credential has Stackdriver logging scope ?

Comment: Yep, I also checked that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to switch your logging resource from `Global` to the specific project that you are logging to per your `gcp-project` opt in the docker command.  There is a `Google Project` option in that menu in the Stackdriver logging UI.